# Efficiently correlate events

Tags: c++, algorithm, events, filter, correlation

I am working on a C++ Windows app and need to add a correlation capability. At the moment I have two event producers, each producer generates similar events. Average combined rate of event generation is 2k/sec for both producers. However, it jumps to 300-500 k/sec under load. This is how a simplified version of an event look like

```
Event
    ProcessId // e.g. 1234 
    Action    // e.g. 0, 1, 2
    Timestamp // e.g. LARGE_INTEGER Windows timestamp
```

The correlation rule I need to build looks like this

```
Filter

    // events are from the same process
    ev1.ProcessId == ev2.ProcessId  

    &&

    // events have specific types
    ( ev1.Action == 0 && ev2.Action == 1) 

    &&

    // they are less than 2 secs apart
    ( abs(ev1.Timestamp - ev2.Timestamp) < 2 seconds)
```

I was thinking about

- a hashmap (ProcessId as key) with queues (for time and action correlation)
- Boost pipelines (example on [github](https://github.com/erenon/pipeline/blob/master/example/join.cpp))

But I am not sure how to deal with fast events eviction as I need to keep CPU and memory  utilization low.

**Can anyone please suggest a solution that will allow me to correlate events efficiently (minimal CPU impact and low memory footprint)?**

Comment: Are you looking for a correlation between the volume of events produced or some characteristic of the events? Is sampling & estimation permissible or do you need an exact measure of correlation?

Comment: It's the characteristic of the events: in a contentious stream of events I need to find those, which match my filter. Maybe the word "correlation" is not exactly right here. Sampling/estimation may introduce errors where I could miss important data, but I think I can apply some filtering to de-duplicate events, as there will be many "near" duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a fairly small window of correlation, you could start by splitting your data there for easy eviction.

Store all objects from stream 1 (the slower/smaller stream) in a cyclic buffer of three hashmaps. When the timestamp of the event you just got is more than two seconds older than the first timestamp you put in the newest hashmap, you empty out the oldest hashmap and put it at the front, moving all others down one step. You also record the "start time" of the first item you are now putting into this bucket.

This allows you to keep a cyclic buffer of roughly 4-6 seconds of data from stream 1, which gives a little buffer against messages not being delivered in the right order.

For stream 2 (the larger/faster stream), you simply do a lookup in all hashmaps. When you get a match, you check that it's actually a real match using your correlation function. This runs in `O(m+b*n log k/b)` for `b` hashmaps (buckets) and `k` messages per second in stream `n`, over the streams of `n` and `m` messages. For `b=3`, you have `O(m + n log k)` for k messages per second in stream `n`. Space requirements should be around `6k`.

If using only three hashmaps makes the performance too spikey (both in terms of memory usage and cpu usage (emptying out hashmaps does take some time)), you could use more hashmaps (increase `b`). Just keep enough for the time you need to hold in memory, plus one or two, and remember the small buffer for late arrivals.